# nodejs express how to get the response of a nested post request

Tags: node.js, express

The following code receives a post request (using the express module), creates a new post request and passes it to another handler:

```
app.post('/commit', function (req, res) {
  ....
  var payload = {
    ....
  };

  request({
    method:'POST',
    body:"payload=" + escape(JSON.stringify(payload)),
    headers:{ '...' },
    url:publicUrl
  }, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(res.statusCode);
  });

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    var obj = {};
    obj['Status'] ="don't know how to get the access code";
    res.end( JSON.stringify( obj ) );
},
```

Now I want to be able to add the actual status code to the json, but I don't know how to access it since I'm sort of in a different scope, right?

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be to try something like this (notice how I moved the code that builds the response to be inside the callback from the POST request):

```
app.post('/commit', function (req, res) {
  ....
  var payload = {
    ....
  };

  request({
    method:'POST',
    body:"payload=" + escape(JSON.stringify(payload)),
    headers:{ '...' },
    url:publicUrl
  }, function (err, postRes, body) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      var obj = {};
      obj['Status'] = 'something went wrong: ' + err;
      res.end( JSON.stringify( obj ) );
    }
    else {
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      var obj = {};
      obj['Status'] = postRes.statusCode;
      res.end( JSON.stringify( obj ) );
    }
  });

},
```